# CentOS mount LAN disk， //192.168.1.223/ is not a valid block device

Tags: centos, mount

I'm using CentOS today, I want mount my work LAN disk in /mnt/P,

use:mount -t cifs //192.168.1.223/ /mnt/P -o username=centos,password=FFM@centos,domain=ffm.local

early, I used this order in Ubuntu, it's OK, but today, in CentOS, tell me:

mount: //192.168.1.223/ is not a valid block device

I don't know much about CentOS, please, thx~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need install `cifs-utils` package

`sudo yum install cifs-utils`